# How To Update All The Visible UITableViewCell Every Time A New Row Appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I want the `UITableView`'s refreshing to be triggered by a new cell's appearing.

Simple setup. `UITableView`, `dataSource` is `[Double]`. Each row in the table will present one number in the array.

The special thing I wanna do is that I want the table to **label the cell with max number of all visible cells**. Then **each of the other cells will calculate the difference from the max number onscreen**. And this should update every time a new cell appears.

[image: the demo of how it should look like]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var max = 0.0
    var data:[Double] = [13,32,43,56,91,42,26,17,63,41,73,54,26,87,64,33,26,51,99,85,57,43,30,33,20]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    private func calculate() {
        // calculate the max of visible cells
        let indexes = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!
        max = indexes
            .map { data[$0.row] }
            .reduce(0) { Swift.max($0,$1) }
        
        // trying to update all the visible cells.

//         tableView.reloadRows(at: indexes, with: .none) ****
//         tableView.reloadData() ****
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row]) : \(max)"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        calculate()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        calculate()
    }
}
```

**What I Have Done**

There are 2 lines of code with marks of **** at the end.

If I uncomment `tableView.reloadRows(at: indexes, with: .none)`, Xcode produces error: `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 15 beyond bounds [0 .. 13]'`. I don't really understand why, but I know onscreen visible cells are at most 14 in order to fit in the screen, but in table loading phase, the simulator thinks there were 19 visible cells at some point

If instead, I uncomment `tableView.reloadData()`, this lines of code will trigger `willDisplay` func which will again call `calculate` func which has `reloadData()` in it. It was a infinite recursive cycle, and no row successfully displayed onscreen.

If instead, I don't uncomment anything, the table will not update cells that are already onscreen. Only newly appearing cells will correctly display the effect that I want.

Thank you for reading all this and trying to offer help.

Comment: You can't reload the cell since that will trigger an infinite loop. In `willDisplayCell` you can use `cellForRow(at:)` to get the cell that is currently on screen and update it directly.

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you so much for the reply. So I deleted ```didEndDisplaying```. I added everything in ```calculate()``` into ```willDisplay```, and added extra code that uses a for-loop to find all cells using ```indexes```, and set their ```textLabel.text``` to new string, and ```cell.setNeedsDisplay()```, but it seemed this code to set the new text was ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call `reloadCells` since that will trigger `willDisplay` and then you get an infinite loop.

Rather, you can access the visible cell and update it directly by calling `cellForRow(at:)` for the visible cells.

```
private func updateVisibleCells() {
    for indexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [] {
        if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row]) : \(max)"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you call `updateVisibleCells` straight after you call `calculate()` in `willDisplayCell` you will get a message in the console:

> Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not allowed.

This will cause a crash in a release build.

To work around this we can defer the call to `updateVisibleCells` by dispatching it asynchronously so that it is called after the table view update is complete:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.calculate()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateVisibleCells()
    }
}
```

You want to use `didEndDisplaying` rather than `willDisplay` so that the rows are updated correctly when rows scroll out of view.  You don't need anything in `willDisplay`

Comment: This code works for me.  My entire view controller is here - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/1d3f043e610f836d35927040b8258085

Comment: Yes, it is important not to confuse the table view method and the data source method (which you shouldn't call yourself)

Comment: Thank you again for your code. But I run into another problem. I changed the ```data``` to ```[100,99,98, ... 1]``` in your code, it works fine except for when it scrolls to the bottom. At the bottom, if I scroll too much, way over the boundary, after letting go, the ```tableView``` will bounce back, but the max will only reflect those rows onscreen when I scroll too much, but won't reflect the rows onscreen after ```tableView``` bouncing back. So in my case, my screen can take 13 rows, I scroll way down until there was 9 rows, then it bounce back, the max then was 9, instead of 13 onscreen.

Comment: I solved it by adding ```updateVisibleCells``` in ```willDisplay cell```. ty